# Travel from USA to India via frankfurt - H1b is valid but stamping expired (i94 expired)

Tags: visas, air-travel, frankfurt

My i94 expired recently but my extension is approved till 2022. Can I travel to India through Frankfurt? I will be going for stamping when I go to India.

Comment: Nationals of the following countries are required to be in possession of an airport transit
visa when passing through the international transit area of airports in Germany:. **India**. Please note that the advance parole (I-512) **and the approval notice (I797) are not valid documents for visa free airport transit**. An aiport
transit visa must be obtained. https://www.germany.info/blob/917514/fffb0bebdc4dca0c6744cc066bc3b7ca/airport-transit-country-list-data.pdf

Answer (score 1):

According to [Germany's Airport Transit Visa requirements document (dated April 2019)](https://www.germany.info/blob/917514/fffb0bebdc4dca0c6744cc066bc3b7ca/airport-transit-country-list-data.pdf), it looks like you can transit through Frankfurt if you meet one of the exception conditions (mentioned only relevant ones, refer doc for full list of exceptions):

> they hold a used valid or expired visa issued by the USA and return from the USA and travel to a non-Schengen Member State **within 24 hours after the expiration of their visa**, or
>
> they hold a valid visa for a Schengen Member State, Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan, Romania or UK, or
>
> they hold a used valid or expired visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Japan, Romania or UK and return from the country of visa issuance and travel to a non-Schengen Member State.